# Meta keywords with variable on blogger

Tags: html, loops, blogger

i will try define meta keywords on templates blogger for each post. 
I use label of post like as keywords.

```
 <b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
      <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
            <a expr:href='data:label.url' rel='tag'><data:label.name/></a><b:if cond='data:label.isLast != &quot;true&quot;'>,</b:if>
      </b:loop>
 </b:if>
```

How i can use above loop to insert below code:

```
<meta content='$Variable' name='Keywords'/>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have implemented this in past but it makes your template dirty

http://www.moretechtips.net/2009/03/blogger-seo-tip-use-post-labels-as-meta.html

This will add some xhtml errors to your template. IMHO I wouldn't care about meta keywords as Google doesn't consider them now days. They have been abused in past.

Answer (score -2):

exactly meta keywords do not effect on ranking nowadays so do not play with codes.  :D